# How to match / connect / pair integers from a List <T>

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph

I have a list, with even number of nodes (always even). My task is to "match" all the nodes in the least costly way.

So I could have `listDegree(1,4,5,6)`, which represents all the odd-degree nodes in my graph. How can I pair the nodes in the `listDegree`, and save the least costly combination to a variable, say `int totalCost`.

Something like this, and I return the least `totalCost` amount.

```
totalCost = (1,4) + (5,6)
totalCost = (1,5) + (4,6)
totalCost = (1,6) + (4,5)
```

--------------- More details (or a rewriting of the upper) ---------------

I have a class, that read my input-file and store all the information I need, like the costMatrix for the graph, the edges, number of edges and nodes.

Next i have a DijkstrasShortestPath algorithm, which computes the shortest path in my graph (costMatrix) from a given start node to a given end node.

I also have a method that examines the graph (costMatrix) and store all the odd-degree nodes in a list.

So what I was looking for, was some hints to how I can pair all the odd-degree nodes in the least costly way (shortest path). To use the data I have is easy, when I know how to combine all the nodes in the list.

I dont need a solution, and this is not homework.

*I just need a hint to know, when you have a list with lets say integers, how you can combine all the integers pairwise.*

Hope this explenation is better... :D

Comment: What is the cost of (1,4) ? or generally (a,b)? how is (1,4) + (5,6) evaluated?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? This reads too much like homework for me to give you a straight answer - not alone before you explain where you are stuck and what you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Perhaps:</strike>

```
List<int> totalCosts = listDegree
            .Select((num,index) => new{num,index})
            .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2)
            .Select(g => g.Sum(x => x.num))
            .ToList();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/YalmCP)

**Edit**:

After you've edited your question  i understand your requirement. You need a total-sum of all (pairwise) combinations of all elements in a list. I would use [**this combinatorics project**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) which is quite efficient and informative.

```
var listDegree = new[] { 1, 4, 5, 6 };
int lowerIndex = 2;
var combinations = new Facet.Combinatorics.Combinations<int>(
    listDegree,
    lowerIndex,
    Facet.Combinatorics.GenerateOption.WithoutRepetition
);

 // get total costs overall
 int totalCosts = combinations.Sum(c => c.Sum());

 // get a List<List<int>> of all combination (the inner list count is 2=lowerIndex since you want pairs)
 List<List<int>> allLists = combinations.Select(c => c.ToList()).ToList();

 // output the result for demo purposes
 foreach (IList<int> combis in combinations)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", combis));
 }
```

Comment: @emo: So does it help, is it correct or does it even answer your question? If so, accept it with the check mark beside the answer. Otherwise tell us what you really need or what does not work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, it didnt help me, thats why i didnt check the mark. I have rewritten my first post, to try to make it more clear. The problem is, I dont see how to make all possible pairwise combinations from af list.

Comment: @ Tim, thank you, I will look at your code and the codeProject link. I found this(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163957.aspx) document my self, so now I should have enough hints. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(Without more details on the cost, I am going to assume `cost(1,5) = 1-5`, and you want the sum to get as closest as possible to 0.)

You are describing the even [**partition problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

The problem says: Given a list `L`, find two lists `A,B` such that `sum(A) = sum(B)` and #elements(A) = #elements(B), with each element from L must be in A or B (and never both).

The reduction to your problem is simple, each left element in the pair will go to A, and each right element in each pair will go to B.

Thus, **there is no known polynomial solution to the problem**, but you might want to try exponential exhaustive search approaches (search all possible pairs, there are `Choose(2n,n) = (2n!)/(n!*n!)` of those).

An alternative is [pseudo-polynomial DP based solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_algorithm) (feasible for small integers).